# Laravel Error : laravelPassport/token 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: laravel-valet

I can't logging into my locale website. I'm getting the following error in the browser console:

> xhr.js:210     POST http://mywebsite.test:3001/_auth/laravelPassport/token 502 (Bad Gateway)

Apps versions:
macos 14.0, Nuxt 2.15.8 frontend, Laravel 10.0 backend, Laravel Passport 11.8, Valet 4.4.1, @nuxtjs/auth-next 5.0, php 8.2.11 installed with brew.

`$ tail -f /Users/gvigner/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log`

> 2023/10/09 17:58:39 [error] 25900#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/me/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "api.test"

`tail -f /usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log`

```
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:10] WARNING: [pool valet] child 26163 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 13.249567 seconds from start
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:10] NOTICE: [pool valet] child 26170 started
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:10] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/me/.config/valet/valet82.sock
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:10] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/me/.config/valet/valet82.sock
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:10] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:10] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:21] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/me/.config/valet/valet82.sock
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:21] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/me/.config/valet/valet82.sock
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:21] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:21] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:31] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/me/.config/valet/valet82.sock
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:31] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/me/.config/valet/valet82.sock
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:31] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[09-Oct-2023 18:00:31] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

How can I fix it?